# SNMP4J: Which SNMP4J Jar should be used to write a SNMP agent?

Tags: snmp, snmp4j

I am new to SNMP agent implementation. A confusion regarding the usage of SNMP4J API is, which SNMP4J Api should be used to create the agent? Should it be SNMP4J or SNMP4J-Agent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An agent is some kind of server: it mainly replies to requests (it may occasionally also send traps to managers).

A manager is a some kind of client: it mainly send requests to agents (it may occasionally also receive traps from managers).

- SNMP4J is the library for managers to send requests to remote agents.
- SNMP4J-Agent is the library for agents to reply to requests.

**So, to write a SNMP agent, you need to use SNMP4J-Agent jar file.**

Comment: thank for the reply! Though, the requirement i have is only to send traps from my server to manager. In that case, should SNMP4J be used or SNMP4J-Agent?

Comment: For you agent to send traps to managers, you need to use SNMP4J-Agent: the method org.snmp4j.agent.NotificationOriginator.notify() that is available in the SNMP4J-Agent jar file is used to send traps.

Comment: Thanks again. Could you also confirm if SNMP4J-Agent is capable of sending SNMPv3 traps?

Comment: Yes, using org.snmp4j.agent.BaseAgent.addUsmUser(). The latest version supports SNMPv3 security schemes based on MD5, SHA-1 an SHA-2 to sign, 3DES and AES to encrypt. I've implemented a SNMPv3 manager with SNMP4J: sources available here https://github.com/AlexandreFenyo/gnetwatch. Developping an agent is not so different.

Comment: I am very much thankful to you for taking me in right direction here. Could you please share an example of sending a basic trap (SNMPv3) via an SNMP4J-Agent?